# Using for Loops to manipulate values within a Numpy Elevation Array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I have an elevation array from a .tif LiDAR surface. Example array below.

```
Existing_example_array = [[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                          [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

My objective is to fill the surface within some tolerance using the below code snippet that will add +1 to any number >= 1

```
geotiff_array = np.array(Existing_example_array)
sub_tif_array = geotiff_array[:]
sub_tif_array[sub_tif_array > 1] += 1

Fill = geotiff_array.tolist()
type(Fill)
```

resulting in the below elevation array:

```
Filled_example_array = [[ 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                        [ 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                        [ 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0], 
                        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                        [ 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0], 
                        [ 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I then use the below code to remove the first and last values in each list:

```
for l in Fill:
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x > 1:
            l[i] -= 100
            break
for l in Fill:
    for i, x in reversed([*enumerate(l)]):
        if x > 1:
            l[i] -= 100
            break
```

Resulting in the below elevation array:

```
    Incorrect_example_array = [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                               [ 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                               [ 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
                               [ 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                               [ 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
                               [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The problem is that the 1 in row 0 gets double counted. I have been solving this problem by manually adding in additional `for loops` that specifically target certain rows where this happens. Is there a way to manipulate the for loops that remove the first and last values in a list to stop when a number has already been changed in the iteration? Or tell the loops to only work within `[1:-1]` to produce the correct elevation array below?

```
    Correct_example_array = [[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                             [ 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                             [ 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
                             [ 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                             [ 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
                             [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't loop. What you want to do can be achieved with a [`binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion):

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion

a = np.array([[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
              [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             ])

a[binary_erosion(a==1, structure=[[1,1,1]])] += 1
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

###### With iterations

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion

a = np.array([[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
              [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             ])

m = a>=1
while True:
    m = binary_erosion(m>=1, structure=[[1,1,1]])
    a += m
    if not m.max(): # if all False, stop
        break
```

Visual representation:

[image]

Comment: Mozway would you be able to elaborate on `a[binary_erosion(a==1, structure=[[1,1,1]])] += 1?` I'm reading your binary_erosion link but I'm not entirely positive I'm grasping the concept.

Comment: Sure, the erosion removes the 1s/Trues that contact 0s/Falses. By default this considers all 8 surrounding cells. Here I changed the behavior to only consider the cells on the left and right by using a different **structure**. To remain a 1, a cell must have a 1 on left and right. Finally we use the output array to select the cells to increment.

Comment: Btw, you could also do `a += binary_erosion(a==1, structure=[[1,1,1]])` ;)

Comment: That makes sense. Would this still be possible to create if i didnt know the values of the numbers? In the example i just used a 1 as a placeholder. If i only knew that the values would be greater than 1 I could add that argument? Also, I'll have to do some additional research, but would this work for the next "ring" of values? By ring I mean this works for the outer ring of numbers but if i wanted to move the function in one number on all sides from the previous iteration.

Comment: Yes, by default `binary_erosion` considers 0 as False and non-zero as True, so this would work. I only added `a==1` for the demo. You could add any numeric or boolean array as input, it will be converted to a boolean array, give it a try. For the iteration, you probably want to consider the output of the erosion as the next input ;)

Comment: I'm looking at the with iterations addition of the answer. Is there a way to stop the code and separate each iteration such that additional calculations can be made? Right now it seems like the code is written to run until it runs out of values to iterate within. The work flow I am trying to accomplish is iteration 1 -> internal calculations -> iteration 2 -> internal calculations etc

Comment: Yes, use a `for` loop with a fixed number of iterations, not an infinite `while` loop. This is just basic python now, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I missed something, but If I change a little bit your code in order to add 1 to the elements in `sub_tif_array >= 1` (notice the equal) and then remove 1 (and not 100) to the first element `> 1` and then again to the last element `> 1`, I obtain the correct result:

```py
import numpy as np
Existing_example_array = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                          [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

geotiff_array = np.array(Existing_example_array)
sub_tif_array = geotiff_array[:]
sub_tif_array[sub_tif_array >= 1] += 1

Fill = sub_tif_array.tolist()

for l in Fill:
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x > 1:
            l[i] -= 1
            break
for l in Fill:
    for i, x in reversed([*enumerate(l)]):
        if x > 1:
            l[i] -= 1
            break
```

Result:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 2 1 0 0]
 [1 2 2 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 2 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0]]
```